# Prefix for nested configuration properties in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE

I have properties class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="person")
public class PersonProperties {

    private AddressProperties addressProperties;

    public AddressProperties getAddressProperties() {
        return addressProperties;
    }

    public void setAddressProperties(final AddressProperties addressProperties) {
        this.addressProperties = addressProperties;
    }

    public static class AddressProperties {

        private String line1;

        public String getLine1() {
            return line1;
        }

        public void setLine1(final String line1) {
            this.line1 = line1;
        }
    }

}
```

And `application.yml`:

```
person:
  address:
    line1: line1OfAddress
```

It is not binding properly as my `AddressProperties` object is `null`.
When a class has the same name as yml properties `AddressProperties` -> `Address` it is working well. I tried to add `Qualifier` or `ConfigurationProperties` with a prefix `address` but it is not working. Unfortunately, I cannot find useful information about this case in spring docs.

How to specify a prefix for nested properties?

Answer (score 3):

Property defined in yaml / property file should match with the variables defined in class.
Either change yaml file as

```
person:
  # addressProperties will also work here
  address-properties:
    line1: line1OfAddress
```

Or define your bean as

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "person")
public class PersonProperties {

    // here variable name doesn't matter, it can be addressProperties as well
    // setter / getter should match with properties in yaml
    // i.e. getAddress() and setAddress()
    private AddressProperties address;

    public AddressProperties getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(AddressProperties address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

If you want to get all properties under address without defining them in separate bean you can define your `PersonProperties` class as

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "person")
public class PersonProperties {

    private Map<String, Object> address;

    public Map<String, Object> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Map<String, Object> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Here `PersonProperties#address` will contain **{line1=line1OfAddress}**

Now All properties under address will be in the `Map`.

Comment: I know it, but I don't want to name my class same as I naming in yaml. As you can see `PersonProperties` is not matching name and we can set prefix. My question is, if I can do it my way or it is not possible.

Comment: @ByeBye Note that you don't have to name the nested class the same as the YAML, just the property itself. Even the instance variable name doesn't have to match the YAML-- only the getter and setter do. So Hemant's second suggestion ('private void setAdddress(AddressProperties address)`) seems like it does what you want, even though it is not the annotation-based solution you were hoping for.

Comment: if this doesn't match by name of the instance, How dose this thing work when a person has two objects like -address--line1--line2           -details--name--phone ?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply un-nest the two classes, allowing each to have it's own prefix.
First class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="person")
public class PersonProperties {

    private AddressProperties addressProperties;

    public AddressProperties getAddressProperties() {
        return addressProperties;
    }

    public void setAddressProperties(final AddressProperties addressProperties) {
        this.addressProperties = addressProperties;
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="person.address")
public class PersonAddressProperties {

    private String line1;

    public String getLine1() {
        return line1;
    }

    public void setLine1(final String line1) {
        this.line1 = line1;
    }
}
```

Edit: As was pointed out in the comments, you'd have to inject both of these classes if one block of code needed to refer to both sets of properties.

Comment: Yeah, but than I need to inject both of them, instead of one

Comment: I think you need to inject both of them, either way. The nested class is a _static_ nested class. It's not an instance variable of the parent class-- for example with the original code if you had a variable `PersonProperty pp` you couldn't write the expression `pp.AddressProperties.line1`.

Comment: I can go with `pp.getAddressProperties().getLine1()`

Comment: That's embarrassing-- I didn't realize that Spring would fill in that nested instance variable automatically. You've helped me than I've helped you, I'm afraid. :-) I'll add a comment to my answer.